# Input Stream error al usar fileupload JAVA JSF

Tags: java, primefaces, fileupload

Estoy subiendo una imagen por primefaces en Java y al usar el input stream me da el Siguente Error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\eclipseLuna\workspaceVsg\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\work\Catalina\localhost\vsg\upload_383ccbdb_b6e0_4892_ba6b_f4ff4fdd5e99_00000006.tmp (El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.getInputStream(DiskFileItem.java:188)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationPart.getInputStream(ApplicationPart.java:100)
at org.primefaces.model.NativeUploadedFile.getInputstream(NativeUploadedFile.java:45)
at cl.ecm.vsg.mantencion.bean.pruebaBean.cargarFoto(pruebaBean.java:120)
at cl.ecm.vsg.mantencion.bean.pruebaBean.cargaFoto(pruebaBean.java:79)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:78)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Estos son los metodos que estoy utilizando:

```
public void uploadFile(FileUploadEvent event) {

    FacesMessage msg = null;
    // System.out.println("\nEntra al metodo ...");
    // Get information you from the uploaded file
    if (event.getFile() != null) {

        // System.out.println("\nNombreArchivo---> " +
        // event.getFile().getFileName());
        // System.out.println("\nTamaño---> " + event.getFile().getSize());

        if (event.getFile().getFileName().contains(".png")
                || event.getFile().getFileName().contains(".jpg")
                || event.getFile().getFileName().contains(".gif")
                || event.getFile().getFileName().contains(".JPG")
                || event.getFile().getFileName().contains(".PNG")) {

            if (event.getFile().getSize() <= 50000) {
                this.setFile(event.getFile());
                this.btnDisableFoto = false;

            } else {
                msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN,
                        "El Archivo No Debe Pesar Mas de 50 KB", "");
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
            }

        } else {
            msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                    "SE DEBE SELECIONAR ARCHIVO CON FORMATO DE IMAGEN", "");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        }

    }

}

public void cargaFoto() {
    if (file != null) {
        cargarFoto(file);
        this.btnDisableFoto = true;
    }
}

public void cargarFoto(UploadedFile file) {
    FacesMessage msg = null;

    File folder = new File(
            ParamSistema.getParametro("PersonalRutaFotoOrigen"));

    if (!folder.exists()) {

        folder.mkdir();
    }

    File files = null;
    File fichero = null;

    try {

        String[] rutDiv = MantenedorClienteBness.divideRut(rutCompleto);
        fichero = new File("id" + rutDiv[0] + rutDiv[1] + ".png");
        files = new File(
                ParamSistema.getParametro("PersonalRutaFotoOrigen")
                        + fichero.toString());

        InputStream input = file.getInputstream();
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(files);

        try {

            IOUtils.copy(input, output);

        } finally {

            IOUtils.closeQuietly(output);
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(input);

        }

    } catch (IOException e1) {

        e1.printStackTrace();

    }

    if (file != null) {

        this.setRutaImagen("");
        this.setRutaImagen(fichero.toString());
        msg = new FacesMessage("Foto Cargado", file.getFileName()
                + " Correctamente.");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);

    } else {

        msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                "Error al Cargar Foto ", "");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
    }

}
```

Le he hecho trazas y el error lo da el file.getInputStream(); ojalas me puedan ayudar. De ante mano gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. ¿Has configurado el `FileUploadFilter` en web.xml? Aquí da alguna información adicional: https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/tutoriales/primefaces-file-upload/

Comment: Gracias por Responder .
Si , lo tengo configurado de la siguiente manera

<filter>
 <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
 <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter
</filterclass>
  <init-param>
   <param-name>thresholdSize</param-name>
   <param-value>1024000</param-value> 
  </init-param>
</filter>
 <filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
 </filter-mapping>

Comment: Ya lo Arrelge , le puse un try catch con un System.out.println(file.getInputStream()) al metodo uploadedFile y quedo solcionado. Gracias

Comment: ¿validar un FileNotFoundException no provocaría problemas en el flujo de tu programa?, me parece que el problema sería encontrar la razón, porque no existe el archivo. @FelipeRojasAlvares agrega tu respuesta en base a [answer], o cierrala si no lo consideras necesario.